# CoCreateInstance fail with error "Class not registered" while using COM visible .NET class

Tags: c#, com

Hello
I created COM visible class MyClass on C# 
registered by regasm command - registration passed OK
And I can see in registry progid corresponding to MyClass 
In the client C++ code : 
1) call of CLSIDFromProgID passed OK 
2) call of CoCreateInstance fail with error "Class not registered" (80040154) 
What can be possible reasons of such behavior - your help will be very valuable 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved executing these commands from the console:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm dllname.dll /tlb:dllname.tlb
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm dllname.dll /regfile
```

then doing a double click on the reg file generated.

to test if everything is ok you can have a very small vb script file which created the object, just put a command like this in a .vbs file:

> SET testObj = CreateObject("Namespace.ClassName")

your COM visible assembly should be strongly named.

Comment: Thanks it works - in the case when not using strong name - you can also use /codebase flag

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that the "class not registered" problem may happen because one uses the incorrect bit-depth version of regasm. The .NET framework comes with 2 versions of regasm.exe. One version in the “Framework” path, and the other in “Framework64″ path.

On my 64 bit machine i got the error when using the 32-bit regasm to register the dll and tried to get an instance from a 64-bit C++ exe.